# After preprocessing csv dataset rebuliding

Tags: python, csv, dataframe

I loaded a csv file for data preprocessing.
After finishing the data preprocessing, not all columns in the csv file are needed. 
So I want to rebuild the csv file by extracting only a few necessary columns. 
What code should I use?

for examples, columns = a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i but I need only a,b,c,d so,

```
before csv file : columns = a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i

after csv file : columns = a,b,c,d
```

*Data set is very large about 6gb
*python 3.6.9
*using pandas

Comment: refer [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) if you are using pandas

Comment: You should include details of the solution you have tried so far, perhaps a specific module and the issue faced with it. The community can help you debug it better that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the method `read_csv` provided by [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html#pandas.read_csv) library, you can read some (and not all) columns from your csv file.

Define a variable like

```
cols = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

that contains the name of columns that you need. After set the argument function `usecols` equal to `cols`:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(path_file, usecols=cols)
```

After all, the dataframe `df` contains values from columns defined in `cols`. Since you're only going to read a few columns, so it'll take you less time!